# Azure Active Directory B2C as a Microservice

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory, microservices, azure-ad-b2c

I've been looking at implementing a Identity Microservice (as per the eShopOnContainers sample ... https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers) and I was wondering if it was possible to implement the Identity Microservice in such a way that you could use any Identity Provider you wanted, including Active Directory B2C?

Perhaps I'm over-thinking this but what I'm asking is, is it possible to have the Identity Microservice loosely coupled to AD B2C?  Are there any examples (in GitHub for example) that demonstrate this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look into IdentityService4 and Auth0.

Comment: I meant IdentityServer4

Comment: Using Azure AD B2C you can have N number of Identity Providers Where the microservices is an architectural style  that structures an application as a collection of loosely coupled services.
In your use case once a user is authenticates to an idenitity provider the dozens of microservices needs to be authenticated. Please check out this [blog](https://nicolgit.github.io/cross-micro-services-authentication-Azure-B2C/) for microservices authentication with Azure AD B2C

Comment: @AndyRefuerzo ... I've had a look at IdentityServer4 but I can't work out a) how to handle user sign-ups and b) if I enable external providers in ADB2C (such as Google,Facebook), can IdentityServer4 still handle that?  I know ID4 can implement Google, Facebook, etc, but I would like it all handled by ADB2C.

Comment: @Raghavendra-MSFTIdentity ... if I go with ADB2C, is it possible to have the sign-in/sign-out/sign-up all accessible through API endpoints ... so I can use Postman for testing?

Comment: As i suggested the reference blog before if you go through that keenly there is an Authority url where we need to specify the policy details. In Azure AD B2C you can build policies with multiple IDPs and you can test the sign-in, signup easly. Please go through the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows) for more insights

Comment: Hi @Dazfl are you still looking for any help on this?

Comment: Hi @Raghavendra-MSFTIdentity ... I'm still reading and investigating ADB2C.  I still can't work out how to expose Login/Register as API endpoints ... but as I said, I'm still investigating

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Please do let us know if any further help needed

Comment: Hi @Raghavendra-MSFTIdentity ... I've discovered Custom Policies with ADB2C and I believe they will solve my issues.  However, can you explain why in the demos/examples I'm seeing, I need to register 3 apps ... basic JWT app, IdentityExperienceFramework app and a ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework app?

Comment: Using Azure AD B2C if we need sign up and sign in users with local accounts (Local accounts exist only in your Azure AD B2C tenant) we need to register two applications (IdentityExperienceFramework, ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework).
For your applications to interaction with Azure AD B2C we need to register application(web application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much reading and research, I ended up using AD B2C directly to authenticate my client apps as well as my API endpoints exposed through Azure API Manager.  My microservices use other forms of authentication as they are only accessible from API Manager (not publicly visible).  I was able to use Custom Policies to implement my own logic when a user signs up/signs in.

Identity Server 4 looks like a great option if you want to have a finer level of control and configuration ... and I may end up using this solution in the future.

But for now, AD B2C meets all my needs so I'm happy to use it as if it was a microservice on its own.

Answer (score 1):

(Moving from comments to Answer)

Using Azure AD B2C you can have N number of Identity Providers Where the microservices is an architectural style that structures an application as a collection of loosely coupled services. In this use case once a user is authenticates to an idenitity provider the dozens of microservices needs to be authenticated. Please check out this [blog](https://nicolgit.github.io/cross-micro-services-authentication-Azure-B2C/) for microservices authentication with Azure AD B2C